# Projection of a Hilbert space onto orthonormal subset.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $H$ and define

$M\equiv span\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$

Show that $M$ is closed and show that if $P$ is the projection of $H$ onto $M$ then $Px=\sum_1^n\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j, \forall x\in H$

**Show that $M$ is closed**

As $M$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space (ie a normed vector space), then we know $M$ is closed.

**Show that $Px$ equals the given sum**

This is the part that is getting to me. Our text does not mention much about projections with orthonormal spaces, so I don't have much to go off. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: $M$ is not a finite subset.  It is, however, a finite dimensional subspace.

Comment: That is what I meant - thank you for the correction.

Comment: For the second, you'll have to look through your book for an official "definition" of a projection onto a subspace, and work from there.

Comment: The projection $Px$ is the point in $M$ closest to $x$. So let $y=\sum \alpha_j e_j$ and find the $\alpha_j$ that minimise $\|y-x\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear projection $P$ onto a subspace $\mathcal{M}$ has the properties that (a) the range of $P$ is $\mathcal{M}$, (b) projecting twice is the same as projecting once: $P^{2}=P$.

Orthogonal projection is something peculiar to an inner product space, and it is the same as closest point projection for a subspace. There can be many projections onto a subspace, but only one orthogonal projection. You would have seen the first examples of this in Calculus where you were asked to find the closest-point projection of a point $p$ onto a line or plane by finding a point $q$ on the line or plane such that $p-q$ is orthogonal to the given line or plane.

The orthogonal projection of a point $p$ onto a closed subspace $\mathcal{M}$ of a Hilbert space is the unique point $m\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $(p-m) \perp\mathcal{M}$. That is $(x-P_{\mathcal{M}}x) \perp \mathcal{M}$ uniquely determines $P_{\mathcal{M}}$, and this function is automatically linear. Orthogonal projection onto a subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is a closest point projection; that is,
$$
                        \|x-m\| \ge \|x-P_{\mathcal{M}}x\|,\;\;\; m \in M,
$$
with equality iff $m=P_{\mathcal{M}}x$.

For your case, the orthogonal projection $Px$ of $x$ onto the subspace spanned by $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{N}$ is the unique $y=\sum_{n}\alpha_{n}e_{n}$ such that $(x-\sum_{n}\alpha_{n}e_{n})\perp \mathcal{M}$. Equivalently,
$$
                 (x-\sum_{n}\alpha_{n}e_{n}, e_{m})=0,\;\;\; m=1,2,3,\cdots,N,
$$
or, using the orthonormality of $\{ e_{n} \}$,
$$
                     (x,e_{m}) = \sum_{n}\alpha_{n}(e_{n},e_{m})=\alpha_{m}.
$$
So the orthogonal projection $P$ onto the subspace $\mathcal{M}$ spanned by $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{N}$ is
$$
                    Px = \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x,e_{n})e_{n}.
$$
By design, one has $(x-Px)\perp\mathcal{M}$. In particular, $(x-Px)\perp Px$ because $Px\in\mathcal{M}$, which gives the orthogonal decomposition $x=Px+(I-P)x$, and
$$
                        \|x\|^{2}=\|Px\|^{2}+\|(I-P)x\|^{2}.
$$
So, both $P$ and $I-P$ are continuous. But $\mathcal{N}(I-P)=\mathcal{M}$ because $Px=x$ iff $x\in\mathcal{M}$, which guarantees that $\mathcal{M}=(I-P)^{-1}\{0\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

For any vector $x$, we can write
$$
x = x^{||} + x^\perp
$$
Where $x^{||} \in M$ is given by $x^{||} = Px$ (as defined by the sum) and $x^{\perp} \in M^{\perp}$.  (In order to verify that $x^{\perp} = x - Px$ is in $M^\perp$, it suffices to note that for each $e_n$, $\langle x - Px,e_n \rangle = 0$.)

Note that for any $y \in M$, we have
$$
\|x- y\|^2 = \|(x^{||} - y) + x^{\perp}\|^2 = 
\|(x^{||} - y)\|^2 + \|x^{\perp}\|^2
$$

Comment: I understand your algebra on the norms, and the idea that $x^\perp = x-Px\in M^\perp$ and that $\langle x-Px,e_n \rangle = 0$... so my goal using this hint should be to show that this $Px$ satisfies the properties of a projection, correct?

Comment: That's exactly right